# Trying to understand networks in Failover Clustering for Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

I am trying to learn failover clustering from videos from CBT Nuggets but I have  question that I hope can be answered. Shown below is the link to the image of the three networks used in the F/O Cluster.

CL1-NUG and CL2-NUG are the cluster nodes, DC-NUG is the domain controller and FS-NUG is the file server node that will act as the shared storage for CL1-NUG and CL2-NUG.

The 192.168.1.0/24 network is the client/company network which is the only network that can go outside to the internet. 
The 192.168.2.0/24 network is the cluster communication network
The 192.168.3.0/24 network is the storage network.

If the 192.168.1.0/24 network allows the clients/company to access FS-NUG at 192.168.1.105, what is the reason for the storage network (192.168.3.0/24)? I know at one point they explain the storage network as a "dedicated network for the nodes to access the shared storage", but why can both the 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 networks access FS-NUG? If you could explain this in layman terms, that would be greatly appreciated.

[The three networks shown in Server Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFkM8.png)

[Diagram of failover cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMcKb.png)

Thanks,